# possible to connect a tcp client on windows to a server on linux?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, client

writing a server that runs on linux (Ubuntu) using mono. and a client that runs on windows using .net, can i connect to the server in linux. i will use c# for both server and client programming.

Comment: Well, sure... this happens every time someone using Windows directs their web browser to a site running on Linux.

Comment: Are you using sockets? Remoting? It is very easy to do in both cases, and yes, it works very well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of the programming language(s) you use, you can always connect a TCP client running on Windows/Linux to a server running on Windows/Linux, with or without .NET. TCP, or Transmission Control Protocol, is Operating System and Programming Language agnostic.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this.  There's nothing special about .Net or any other language/platform the would require a tcp service to only work with that specific language or platform. It's all just tcp in the end.